# Testing keyboard and touch capabilities in Windows 8

Tags: c#, xna, windows-runtime, touch, monogame

I'm writing a game using monogame for Windows 8.  It has two methods of control; where there's a keyboard present, it uses that; otherwise, where touch is available, it uses that.  However, although I can simulate touch using the simulator, I can't find a way to simulate that either or both of these capabilities are unavailable (other that to simply turn off that capability in code)?

```
// Determine if a keyboard is present and change the input mode accordingly
Windows.Devices.Input.KeyboardCapabilities kc = 
     new Windows.Devices.Input.KeyboardCapabilities();
if (kc.KeyboardPresent == 1)
    settings.InputMode = Settings.InputModeSettings.Keyboard;
else
{
    Windows.Devices.Input.TouchCapabilities tc = 
        new Windows.Devices.Input.TouchCapabilities();
    if (tc.TouchPresent == 1)
        settings.InputMode = Settings.InputModeSettings.Touch;
```

Comment: Why do you have to simulate that some capabilities are unavailable?  
You can simply detect only the input you want to simulate.

Comment: Yes, but that means changing the code to test.  I can (and have) tested by simply jumping through the code manually to check it does what I expect; but it would be nice if there were some facility in the simulator to say "device has keyboard" or "device has touch"

Comment: I don't think you can do something like this on the simulator, it will always detect mouse, touch and keyboard as input.

Comment: I'm not sure how to simulate the keyboard missing but to simulate touch missing I've temporarily disabled the touch driver as described here: http://fixedbyvonnie.com/2014/04/disable-touch-screen-display-computer/#.U4quPfldV8E